# Can't step into/break on my code with qt creator

Tags: c++, linux, qt, debugging

I have created a project in qt creator with multiple subdirs and am deploying/running it on a beaglebone. Compiles fine, deploys fine, etc.

My issue is that when I try to debug, the only files I can set breakpoints in or step into are those in the same subdir where main.cpp is. Just to test, I duplicated the project with a flat folder structure and can set breakpoints and step into everything.

When the debugger starts up, the debug log tries to set the breakpoints and fails seemingly because it can't find the .cpp files:

> "No source file named projectdir/dir1/myclass.cpp.\n"
>   8045^done,bkpt={number="1",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="",pending="\"projectdir/dir1/myclass.cpp\":7",times="0",original-location="\"fullpathofprojectdir/dir1/myclass.cpp\":7"}

Whereas it says this for breakpoints in main:

> 8046^done,bkpt={number="2",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x0001831c",func="main(int, char**)",file="projectdir/dir2/main.cpp",fullname="fullpathofprojectdir/dir2/main.cpp",line="27",thread-groups=["i1"],times="0",original-location="fullpathofprojectdir/dir2/main.cpp:27"}

Additionally, myclass.cpp doesn't show up in the source files panes either. How can I resolve this?

Here is the setup of my *.pro files:

Top level project file:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS += \
   dir1 \
   dir2

unix {
    target.path = /home/debian
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

Project file of library (dir1, myclass.cpp, etc):

```
QT       -= gui

TARGET = Common
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += COMMON_LIBRARY

SOURCES += \
    myclass.cpp

HEADERS += \
    common_global.h \ 
    myclass.h

unix {
    target.path = /home/debian/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}

CONFIG += debug
```

Project file containing main:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Test
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp 

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../Common/release/ 
-lCommon
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -
L$$OUT_PWD/../Common/debug/ -lCommon
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../Common/ -lCommon

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../Common
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../Common

target.path = /home/debian
INSTALLS += target
```

Let me know if there's any other relevant data I forgot to provide. Qt Creator version is 4.5.0 and I'm running it on a 64 bit VM of ubuntu 16.04 if that's relevant.

Comment: Have you tried clean, run qmake again and rebuild?

Comment: @A.A yes, but it doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: It's strange that the file does not appear in the source view. And what's about these `projectdir` and `fullpathofprojectdir`? What about putting space after dir1 "dir1 \"

Comment: `projectdir` and `fullpathofprojectdir` are just my shorthand for where the root of the qt project is, sorry for the confusion.  I checked them with the terminal eg `nano projectdir/dir1/myclass.cpp` and it worked as expected. As for putting a space after dir1 in the top level .pro, there is one in the actual project but made a typo when I put it here. Good eye

Comment: When you did the make clean, did you delete all the Qt generated hidden folders and files—i.e., .stash, .mocs, .objs, .uics, and all the make files?

Comment: Also, in the debugger options, did you choose to set breakpoints with full absolute path?